# Usage of 'someone gets someone familiar with something'

Tags: phrase-usage

I can't find the exact answer to the question of whether 'someone gets someone familiar with something' sounds correct and natural in English?

When I googled a while, I discovered that speakers of English said that when referring to a tour or a guide or training sessions. But I want to say that, for example, in the following context

> A manager at work offered to get a new colleague familiar with the affairs of the company.

In my dictionary I also looked up other phrases with the same meaning.

> make someone familiar;
>
> have someone familiar.

Are they more suitable for this context? A talk in a loose manner or ambiguity is not appropriate here.

Comment: The normal, less colloquial form is _familiarise someone with something_. Of the less formal alternatives, I'd use 'make' or perhaps 'get'.

Comment: When I was a kid, I just took it for granted to follow people around me to use "get" as just another aux verb. But of course, as kid, I did not know they were called *aux verbs*.

Comment: @Blessed Geek _Get_ is not used as an auxiliary here: there is no other verb present. This is a resultative construction. 'They got him drunk' cf 'They painted it red'. 'The man wiped the table clean' cf 'They got him involved' / 'They got him involved with the ebola victims'.

Comment: _make_ is acceptable, although uncommon I think. _have_ seems totally wrong, though.

Comment: @Barmar could you confirm again: have is totally wrong, make is uncommon, get is ok but too informal?

Comment: Yeah, that's about it. Sometimes you hear something like _have someone become familiar_.

Answer (score 1):

As Edwin Ashworth notes in a comment above, it is less awkward (as well as being perfectly formal) to say

> A manager at work offered to familiarize a new colleague with the company's affairs.

than to say

> A manager at work offered to get [or *make*] a new colleague familiar with the affairs of the company.

Another option is to use the verb *acquaint* in place of *familiarize*:

> A manager at work offered to acquaint a new colleague with the company's affairs.

Answer (score 0):

For general purposes, a better idea would be to use: "have (pronoun) familiarize himself." Not only does it achieve your goal without awkward phrasing, but it's less wordy. Example:

*A manager at work offered to have a new colleague familiarize himself with the affairs of the company.*

However, this sentence indicates that it is the said colleague familiarizing himself. So, for *your* purposes, you will most likely want to use:

*A manager at work offered to **help** a new colleague familiarize himself with the affairs of the company.*

Or, to be more formal,

*A manager at work offered to **assist** a new colleague **in** familiariz**ing** himself with the affairs of the company.*